# Bias resistor in opamp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors, bias

For the circuit below, what is the purpose of the 2 bias resistors.
They are said to detect breaking, what does it mean.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

If the sensor wires open up, then those two resistors will pull the voltages way apart, and that huge voltage signifies a broken wire.

Comment: +1, excellent answer